# Debug output in the Kernel module

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I want to include debug output in my kernel module, in which the content of the variable cnt (data type unsigned int) is output.

Which function available in the kernel can i use?

What is the call to this function for the above task?

How can I view the output on the console?

Comment: See [Message logging with printk](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-basics.html) for adding debug logging to your code. You can use the `dmesg` command to display the current contents of the kernel log buffer.

Comment: So in the code it would look like this:    printk (KERN_INFO "value of cnt:% x \ n", cnt); .        But how can I view the output on the console?

Comment: You can use the `dmesg` command on its own to display the current contents of the log buffer. The `dmesg` command also has various options to control live logging to the console, as described in its man page.

Comment: Ok thanks @Ian Abbott :)

Comment: @oeztuerk_42, `pr_info()` is better. Also read about formatting hings in SO comments. You may use, e.g., backquoted text.